# Embedded Ruby in text fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm testing the text part of an email in my Rails application and I have a text fixture to test against. The fixture is not a `.yml` file since it's just text to test against. However, the email contains the current year (like 2010-2018) and I'm trying to see if I can use erb in that text fixture so I can test my email without having to update it every year.

This is how I'm currently using the textfile:

textfile

```
...
Copyright 2006-2018
```

test file:

```
assert_equal read_fixture('textfile').join, email.text_part.body.to_s
```

Comment: Don't use `assert_equal` on an entire email body. Use `assert_match` to spot-check the parts that might be fragile, such as the current year.

Comment: I'll think about your approach. I would probably need multiple `assert_match` to test this? If you don't mind, can you give me an example of how you would use `assert_match` to test this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using multiple `assert_match` statements - it'll make it clear, readable and easy to change in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use rails fixtures you can mix ERB in with your YAML fixtures(don't need to add "erb" extension to the filename):

```
# fixtere_name.yml
one:
  column: <%= DateTime.now %>
```

When you use own fixtures or similar files you can manually execute ruby parts. For example:

```
# fixtere.txt
some text <%= DateTime.now.year %>

# load this fixture
fixture = ERB.new File.read("path/to/fixture.txt"), nil, "%"
fixture.result(binding) # => "some text 2018\n"
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the `nil, "%"` part? I'm not sure what those would do

Comment: nil - safe_mode, % - enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %.
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new

Comment: Thank you! I never knew you could manually execute ERB in text files like that!